# Find All Rows in DataTable Where Column Value is NOT Unique Using Linq Query

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, dataset

I am attempting to write a Linq to SQL query that returns all rows in a DataTable where a columns value (TxnNumber) is not unique.  So far, I have the Linq to SQL below where dt is the DataTable that contains the field TxnNumber.  I think that I am pretty close but, intellisense is complaining about the CONTAINS clause.  I have tried specifying that I only want to return the TxnNumber field in the sub-select but, it will not compile.  Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```
dt.AsEnumerable().Where(u => u.TxnNumber.Contains (dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(t => t.TxnNumber).Count() > 1));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
(from r in dt.AsEnumerable()
group r by r.TxnNumber into grp
where grp.Count() > 1
select grp).SelectMany(x=>x).ToList();
```